# How to implement Azure MobileAppController C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have 2 TableController for 2 my tables. Also I need another controller, which process data from tables.

Azure's [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller) says I should declare ApiController following way:

```
[MobileAppController]
public class CustomController : ApiController
{
      //...
}
```

But I don't realize how to get any data from tables to process it.
I tried to create new instance of Table's Controller, but it doesn't work such way. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage the tables within your custom API, just use regular entity framework code.  You can find a tutorial here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/introduction.aspx