# What to code/do inside the custom created Azure Mobile C# backend ApiController?

Tags: .net, azure-mobile-services

How or What to code inside the custom created ApiController?

Sorry, Im new to .NET as well as Azure Mobile App Service

I've downloaded the Azure quickstart C# runtime pack.

The Azure Official Documentation doesn't shows complete guide, and I've no idea what to do inside the custom API controller:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-define-a-custom-api-controller

IMAGE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mG9K.png

After I follow the step, create an empty ApiController published and mobile client side (Android_QuickStart_Pack) are no longer connected anymore. I cant found any solution out there with detail guide and complete tutorial how to work on this.

According to the Adrian Hall's answer in this question:
[How to implement Azure MobileAppController C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181543/how-to-implement-azure-mobileappcontroller-c-sharp)

I have no idea how to link up this with the Azure Mobile App Service

> > www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/introduction.aspx

Sorry again I'm really new to this. Please suggest a tutorial to work on this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a whole series on this.  This particular blog post: https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/13/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-20-custom-api/ will give you information on Custom APIs.

On a different note, if you are trying to learn C#, ASP.NET, Entity Framework and Azure Mobile Apps all at the same time, it's probably too much.  Are you more comfortable in JavaScript?  Perhaps the Node.js backend is better?  If you are new to programming, I suggest learning the underlying technologies individually before jumping into the most complex subjects.